# Ruby iterator block focus into parameter?

Tags: ruby, foreach, parameters

I have a large iterator where I need to insert a loop-count integer into parameters into the params captured by my Sinatra post.

I can't figure out how to augment the parameter (`:s_fieldname_i`) in the loop.  I want to reference the loop-count in the last `i`.  I've simplified the loop in order to demonstrate the challenge here:

```
    1.upto(@count) do |i|
        @f += " <label for=\"" + params[:s_fieldname_i] + "\">" + params[:s_fieldname_i.capitalize!] + "</label>\n"
    end
```

I tried some string interpolation (`#{i}`) but that only confused it more.  I'm sure there's a way to get this done.

Comment: Don't use `for` in Ruby. Instead, iterate over the block using `each` or `times` or `upto`.

Comment: See edit.  Still the same issue internally.

Comment: It's not necessary, or recommended, to add "Edit:" or "Updated" type markers. Adjust the code as necessary to reflect its current state, and make sure the question is current and matches the code. We can see if you've changed something, and what you changed if it's necessary. As is, our code doesn't match your "Edit" so please reedit your question to make sense. It helps us help you.

Comment: Actually, if I just edit the code, then the comments make no sense.  See, in a science degree, you are encouraged to edit things, not just change them.  That way the progression of the conversation makes sense.  The only way you can make any sense of what was changed, is if what was first submitted is also there.  Specifically to this case, it's not rocket science to follow.  It doesn't help anybody when remedial things like this get attacked, especially when supporting nonsensical results when following a conversation.

Comment: As well, what you commented on had nothing to do with the question.  Outside of how the loop was initiated, the question still remained.  It is recommended that comments pertain to the question, and not what you want to talk about.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a discussion board, it's closer to a reference book or cookbook of solutions to problems. Comments are used to gain clarification and provide feedback about the question to the asker, including how the site is used. Adding "Update" or "Edit" tags doesn't fit the accepted style of the site and will get edited out. [meta] is a great resource to discuss these things.

Comment: If that is the case, then stick to the problem and not wander off what was asked.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you should try to avoid string concatenation as it will explode your app if any one of the params value becomes `nil` at some point.

Try this using string interpolation, I think you are looking for something like this:

```
1.upto(@count) do |i|
  @f += "<label for='#{params[:s_fieldname_i]}'> #{params[:s_fieldname_i.capitalize!]}</label>\n"
end
```

Comment: @f += " <label for='#{params[:s_fieldname_i]}'>" resolves <label for=''>.  So that demonstrates it's just blind throughout that whole interpolation.  That approach seems great if it could be accomplished.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, factoring it out into a seperate variable can make it easier.

```
1.upto(@count) do |i|
    fieldname = "s_fieldname_#{i}".to_sym
    @f += " <label for=\"" + params[fieldname] + "\">" + params[fieldname.capitalize!] + "</label>\n"
end
```

Comment: It's so close. @f += params[@fieldname] throws an error on output of @f, but @f += @fieldname renders just fine.  Coercing to .to_sym also throws an error.

Comment: What error are you getting for `@f += params[fieldname]`?

Comment: First off, I had to change that definition to @fieldname = "s_fieldname+#{i}".to_sym.  Then, that became confusing when it would need the ATfieldname in the build.  Trying ATfieldname (after solving for a string coerce demand) renders nothing, as does :fieldname.  So both options don't resolve at all.  (sorry, at signs screw up postings here)

Comment: Why do you need to change it to `@fieldname`?

Comment: This is Sinatra.  So it has to be an instance.  I'm just coming back to this so let me get my head around it again.  Will post later.  Thanks.

Comment: Found it.  Was a juggling of strings and iterator i, coercing to concat string as the key.  Leaving symbols completely out of it.

Answer (score 0):

```
@key = "s_fieldname_" + i.to_s
@f += " <label for=\"" + @h[("s_fieldname_" + i.to_s)].to_s + "\">"
```

Leaving symbols out and coercing the iterator i to string, makes for a workable key.